# How to match items in R based on some criteria?

Tags: r

So, off the bat I think I need something along the lines of the R package ‘fuzzyjoin’, or maybe it can actually work but I then need help on how to get it to work.

I have two data frames df1 and df2. Each data frame has 7 columns. The columns are: id; type 1; type 2; criteria 1; criteria 2; criteria 3; criteria 4.

df1 has, let's say, 500 rows, whereas df2 has let's say 2000 rows. Here is a small excerpt to make clearer what I have in mind.

```
df1

id      type 1  type 2  criteria 1      criteria 2  criteria 3  criteria 4
214     CAF     A+      19.76338        44078       0.7         45904
312     BZD     B+      17.21671        43333       3.385       45159
```

```
df2

id  type 1  type 2  criteria 1  criteria 2  criteria 3  criteria 4
66    CAF   B+      20.50012    43963       2.375       45058
163   CAF   B       20.72327    42640       2.125       44466
188   CAF   A+      21.12873    41075       4.375       44727
250   CAF   A+      20.43558    43427       3.75        45253
345   CAF   A-      18.45072    43669       10.4        45496
357   CAF   A+      20.72327    43046       2.75        44932
520   CAF   AA      19.1687     41586       6.25        45238
609   CAF   A+      19.32814    42160       4.5         45813
637   CAF   A-      19.32038    42808       4.5         46644
791   CAF   AA      18.79739    42460       4.5         46295
846   BZD   B+      18.07695    43399       3.4         45225
854   BZD   A+      18.0598     43992       7.5         47644
885   BZD   A+      19.15586    42818       3.265       46470
1026  BZD   B+      18.9031     41694       3.925       47175
1045  BZD   Aaa     17.49807    42412       0.45        46065
1121  BZD   BB      18.12462    42087       0.68        45740
1176  BZD   A+      18.05427    41709       3.05        47553
```

For each row in df1, I want to find the best matching row in df2 such that type 1 and type 2 are ***identical*** for both df1 and df2, and then the criteria 1 to criteria 4 are *as close as possible* but do not necessarily have to be exactly identical (indeed they are unlikely to be). Preferably, if possible, I'd like to use the Mahalanobis distance for the criteria but this isn't strictly necessary.

Does anyone know which package or function I can use for this?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of by pasting the output of ``dput(df1)`` and ``dput(df2))`` into your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
df1 = tribble(
 ~id, ~type1, ~type2, ~criteria1, ~criteria2, ~criteria3, ~criteria4, 
 1, "CAF","A+", 19.76338, 44078, 0.7, 45904, 
 2, "BZD","B+", 17.21671, 43333, 3.385, 45159,
 3, "CAF", "A+", 22.12873, 45075, 4.365, 42727,
 4, "BZD","B+", 15.21671, 43333, 3.385, 45159,
 5, "BZD","B+", 16.21671, 43333, 3.385, 45159
)

df2 = tribble(
 ~id, ~type1, ~type2, ~criteria1, ~criteria2, ~criteria3, ~criteria4, 
 66, "CAF", "B+", 20.50012, 43963, 2.375, 45058,
 163, "CAF", "B", 20.72327, 42640, 2.125, 44466,
 188, "CAF", "A+", 21.12873, 41075, 4.375, 44727,
 250, "CAF", "A+", 20.43558, 43427, 3.75, 45253,
 345, "CAF", "A-", 18.45072, 43669, 10.4, 45496,
 357, "CAF", "A+", 20.72327, 43046, 2.75, 44932,
 520, "CAF", "AA", 19.1687, 41586, 6.25, 45238,
 609, "CAF","A+", 19.32814, 42160, 4.5, 45813,
 637, "CAF", "A-", 19.32038, 42808, 4.5, 46644,
 791, "CAF", "AA", 18.79739, 42460, 4.5, 46295,
 846, "BZD", "B+", 18.07695, 43399, 3.4, 45225,
 854, "BZD", "A+", 18.0598, 43992, 7.5, 47644,
 885, "BZD", "A+", 19.15586, 42818, 3.265, 46470,
 1026, "BZD","B+", 18.9031, 41694, 3.925, 47175,
 1045, "BZD", "Aaa", 17.49807, 42412, 0.45, 46065,
 1121, "BZD", "BB", 18.12462, 42087, 0.68, 45740,
 1176, "BZD","A+", 18.05427, 41709, 3.05, 47553
)

addCrit = function(df_1, df_2){
  df_2 %>% 
    filter(type1==df_1$type1 & type2==df_1$type2) %>% 
    nest(data=criteria1:criteria4) %>% 
    mutate(
      crit = map_dbl(data, crit, df_1),
      id2 = id
    ) %>% 
    arrange(crit) %>% 
    select(id2, crit) %>% 
    head(1)
}

crit = function(df1, df2) sqrt(
    (df1$criteria1-df2$criteria1)^2+
    (df1$criteria2-df2$criteria2)^2+
    (df1$criteria3-df2$criteria3)^2+
    (df1$criteria4-df2$criteria4)^2)
    

df1 %>% 
  nest(data=type1:criteria4) %>% 
  mutate(
    cr = map(data, addCrit, df2)
  )  %>% unnest(c(cr, data))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 9
     id type1 type2 criteria1 criteria2 criteria3 criteria4   id2   crit
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 CAF   A+         19.8     44078      0.7      45904   250  921. 
2     2 BZD   B+         17.2     43333      3.38     45159   846   93.3
3     3 CAF   A+         22.1     45075      4.36     42727   357 2996. 
4     4 BZD   B+         15.2     43333      3.38     45159   846   93.4
5     5 BZD   B+         16.2     43333      3.38     45159   846   93.4
```

Make the `crit` function as you see fit. It can be the Mahalanobis criterion or anything else.
This function takes two single-line data frames and returns the value of the criterion as a `double` value.

Comment: Hi. I am trying this with a much larger dataset and am obtaining the following error. Is this because too many possible matches occur, or what is the problem?
` Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cr`.
i `cr = map(data, addCrit, df2)`.
x Problem with `mutate()` column `crit`.
i `crit = map_dbl(data, crit, df_1)`.
x Result 1 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 9
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
`

Comment: Check the purity of your data. Are you sure the `criteria1: criteria4` variables will contain only `dbl` values?

Comment: So using `typeof()` and `class()`, each of `criteria1:criteria4` are all apparently `double` and `numeric`. Hence I think the data types should be correct?

Comment: Can you share this data with me then?  I'll check it for you.  If for some reason you cannot share the data with me, divide it in half and test when you get an error.  Repeat this halving that causes the error.  This way you will quickly identify the problem.